# ModelService.save(dispute) is removing the Object record from db in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I  fetched the record to be updated from the db and updated the details and saved again , process goes on without any flaw but dont know why the record gets deleted after getting saved.

```
AviationDisputeModel dispute = aviationDisputeService.getDisputeDetails(resolveDisputeDetails.get("DispId").toString());
    if (Objects.nonNull(dispute) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(String.valueOf(resolveDisputeDetails.get("DispId")))
            && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(String.valueOf(resolveDisputeDetails.get("DspStat")))
            && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(String.valueOf(resolveDisputeDetails.get("RES_CODE"))))
    {
        try
        {
            dispute.setDisputeStatus((resolveDisputeDetails.get("DspStat").toString()));
            dispute.setResolutionCode(resolveDisputeDetails.get("RES_CODE").toString());
            dispute.setDisputeCategory(resolveDisputeDetails.get("RES_CODE").toString());
            dispute.setResolutionCategory(resolveDisputeDetails.get("RES_CODE").toString());
            modelService.save(dispute);
            return "SUCCESS";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LOG.error("Error while resolving Dispute" + e.getMessage());
            return "FAILURE";
        }
```

Comment: Maybe there is a interceptor exits and removing wrong items.

Comment: @mkysoft i checked but there is no such interceptor

Comment: Create new interceptor for remove event and try to find source from call stack.

Comment: Hi @mkysoft you were right there was an interceptor which was not removing the dispute but generating a different id and saving it Thanks

Comment: @mkysoft please convert your comment into an answer